# how to send info on email using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

i have made a solution for my web site using jquery. which creates a table with product quantity and its price now i want to send this info on my email with some other additional info e.g customer name and customer email id. as i am new to jquery i don't have any idea how to do it below is my html and j query code with link to jsfiddle

HTML:

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&Oslash;nsket Antal :</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;"><input type="text" name="Quantity" id="quantity" /><input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value="18150" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="blue" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: small; text-align: -webkit-center;"><b>Pris: pr. stk/enhed&nbsp;<font color="red">18.150,00 Kr.</font></b></font><span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: small; text-align: -webkit-center;">&nbsp;</span><a id="fck_paste_padding">﻿</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" id="AddProduct" name="Add Product" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#AddProduct').click(function() {
    var quan = $('#quantity').val();
    var pri = $('#price').val();
    var totalPrice = $('#price').val() * $('#quantity').val();
    var table = $('<table class="t" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td width="15%" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font color="blue" face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Antal</strong></font></td><td width="10%" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font color="blue" face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Vare</strong></font></td><td width="40%" align="left" valign="middle"><font color="blue" face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Beskrivelse</strong></font></td><td width="15%" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font color="blue" face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>á Pris</strong></font></td><td width="15%" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font color="blue" face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>i alt</strong></font></td></tr><tr><td width="15%" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">'+ quan +'</font></td><td width="15%" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">138</font></td><td width="40%" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">30 skrm Kløvet Ask brænde</font></td><td width="15%" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">Kr.'+ pri +'</font></td><td width="15%" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">Kr.'+ totalPrice +'</font></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">Subtotal:</font></td><td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">Kr.'+ totalPrice +'</font></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">Levering:</font></td><td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">Kr.0,00<input type="hidden" name="intShipping" value="0,00"></font></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2">Af beløbet udgør de 550,00 kr. <a title="Click to Continue > by safesaver" id="_GPLITA_1" style="text-decoration:underline" href="#" in_rurl="http://i.tracksrv.com/click?v=REs6NTAzMzg6NDptb21zOmJhYzllZWI0NzZkOWJmNDAzNmNhOTA5OTFjNjIwYzlmOnotMTQ5OS0yMDA1MTM6d3d3LmJsYWFraWxkZS5jb206MDowOjEzNzkzMjg0NjM3Mjc">moms</a> på 25%</font></td><input type="hidden" name="intTax" value="550,00"></tr><tr><td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>TotalOrdre incl. moms og levering:</b></font></td><td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap=""><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Kr.'+ totalPrice +'<input type="hidden" name="intTotal" value="2.750,00"></b></font></td></tr></tbody></table>');
       $('#solution').html(table);
    });
    });
```

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TQrX/1/)

Comment: jQuery can not send mail as its client side scripting so i suggest you to look forward to use serverside script like php or asp.

Comment: Take a look at AJAX , and Hidden fields

Comment: Funny to add `font-family` style to the `<font>` tag...