# Send data form to a specific email

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I want to send my data form that user type to a specific email. Example:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your name"/>
 <input type="email" placeholder="Your email"/>
 <textarea name="content"></textarea>
 <input type="button" onclick="sendmail()"/>
</form>
```

When user clicks the button, an email will be sent  to a specific address like admin@admin.com with email's content is what user type in the form. Can we reach that result with only JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: its a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844497/how-to-send-info-on-email-using-jquery, search here and post questions.

Comment: yes you can reach that result with javascript

Comment: How can we do it with only JS,Sora? I am not familiar with PHP but I will try the solution in Biby's comment

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without additional modules :

[This](http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/34641712180/sending-email-from-node-js) is a good tutorial , you could create a dedicated address reported@yoursite.com and have it email your admin address when a user registers

Comment: my server doesn't support nodejs, so I think I will use php as a solution

Comment: I wasn't aware your entire stack wasn't js based, you should make this clearer in your post in future! Hope you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="emailLnk" >send mail</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#emailLnk").click(function(){
     document.location.href = "mailto:xyz@something.com";
 });
});​
</script>
```

Comment: The OP wants an e-mail to be sent automatically, without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless someone took the time to rewrite a SMTP client or sendmail in JavaScript, which is not the case. Moreover, that would mean giving away the SMTP password (which is bad) or not using a SMTP at all, meaning that almost all free/commercial providers will reject your e-mail.

You should set up a minimal PHP script to receive a POST request and forward the body as e-mail to your designed account. You should be able to do it in a handful of lines.

Comment: I have never used PHP before but I will try